# How to parse the JSON in android?

Tags: android

```
 "carMake": {
            "Tata": [
                "FIAT",
                "INDICA VISTA",
                "INDIGO XL"
            ],
            "Hyndai": [
                "SANTRO Xing",
                "I10",
                "I20",
                "ACCENT",
                "SONATA"
            ]
        },
```

I just need to parse this part in my response. I tried with map but I am not getting it solved.

Comment: Didn you get any information/help from Google !

Comment: Please look at all the questions in the "Related" section to the right of this page.

Answer (score 1):

use gson.
http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a JSON Object parser.

Here's a link to an example http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_JSON_Parser_Example

Answer (score 0):

See the bellow example.

The response string is like this

```
 String jsonStr = '{"menu": {' + 
        '"id": "file",' + 
        '"value": "File",' + 
        '"popup": {' + 
          '"menuitem": [' + 
            '{"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},' + 
            '{"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},' + 
            '{"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}' + 
          ']' + 
        '}' + 
      '}}';
```

use the bellow code to parse the json String

```
   // grabbing the menu object 
   JSONObject jsonObf=new JSONObject(jsonStr);
   JSONObject menu = jsonObj.getJSONObject("menu"); 

  // these 2 are strings 
  String id = menu.getString("id");   
  String value = menu.getString("value"); 

  // the popop is another JSON object 
  JSONObject popup = menu.getJSONObject("popup"); 

  // using JSONArray to grab the menuitems from under popop  
  JSONArray menuitemArr = popupObject.getJSONArray("menuitem");  

  // lets loop through the JSONArray and get all the items 
  for (int i = 0; i < menuitemArr.length(); i++) { 
       // printing the values to the logcat 
      Log.v(menuitemArr.getJSONObject(i).getString("value").toString()); 
      Log.v(menuitemArr.getJSONObject(i).getString("onclick");
 }
```

In your case, do the simple modifications to achieve the solution.